# Qt setFilter searching?

Tags: c++, sqlite, qt

I have question about using void `QSqlTableModel::setFilter(const QString &filter)`. I
have database SQL lite and I have to do a button, that searches in the database certain names. So I
created the QLine Edit object (I am working in qt creator) and I don't know how to display that name that I wrote in line. Thank you for every response and sorry for my bad English and kids
question, but I don't know and my deadline is coming light speed

```
 void MainWindow::on_pushButton_3_clicked()
{
QString edit = ui->lineEdit->text();
model->setFilter("Název = ""'+edit+'");
model->select();
}
```

Comment: use `model->setFilter("Název = '"+edit+ "'");`

Comment: or `model->setFilter(QString("Název = '%1'").arg(edit));`

Comment: I try this                                                                                                                      
   model = new QSqlTableModel(this, db);
    const QString edit = ui->lineEdit->text();
     model->setTable("Filmy");
    //qDebug()<<edit;
    model->setFilter("Název == Pád do tmy");
   //model->setFilter(QString("Název = '%1'").arg(edit));
    model->select();
    ui->tableView->setModel(model);                                                                                               but nothing happend, do you know why? please